# Improvements to search algorithm

Tags: c++, c++11, stl-algorithm

I'm implementing a monitor system which checks if processes are running on the computer and then handles their restart/recovery if they are not. To do this I have the following function:

```
std::size_t ProcessPolicy::is_running_with_restart(
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator begin,
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator end,
    std::function<void( std::string const & )> func )
{
    auto running_processes = std::vector<std::string>{};

    {
        //--------------
        //Platform specific code to populate the vector
        //with the names of all running processes
        //--------------
    }


    //sort both the lists
    if ( std::is_sorted( begin, end ) == false )
    {
        std::sort( begin, end );
    }

    auto running_begin = std::begin( running_processes );
    auto running_end = std::end( running_processes );

    std::sort( running_begin, running_end );


    //compare sorted lists processing differences
    auto count = std::size_t{ 0 };

    std::for_each(
        begin,
        end,
        [func, &running_begin, &running_end]( std::string const &curr ) {

            running_begin = std::find_if(
                running_begin,
                running_end,
                [&curr]( std::string const &s ) {
                    return ( s.compare( curr ) >= 0 );
                } );

            if ( running_begin != running_end )
            {
                if ( *running_begin != curr )
                {
                    func( curr );
                    ++count;
                }

                ++running_begin;
            }
            else
            {
                func( curr );
                ++count;
            }

        } );


        return count;
    }
```

This function is working but I'm wondering whether there is a more elegant way to do this?

=== EDIT ===

To be specific, I'm not looking for a code review and this is a hypothetical situation (not a university/work assignment either) I came up with in order to expand my knowledge of std algorithms. What I'm asking is...

*Given two std containers of strings (A and B), is there an algorithm in the standard library which can create a third container (C) that holds copies of elements from A which are not present in B.*

Comment: Code reviews would be better off on [codereview.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: As it stands, this code won't fly on Code Review. He'd have to include *complete*, compilable code for it to go on Code Review.

Comment: I assume you are doing this for academic purposes because there are already quite a few programs that do this, and one or more of them is usually included in any modern operating systems package repository already.. If I'm wrong, then why *not* just use one of the standard options?

Comment: You may look at algorithm `std::set_intersection`/`std::set_difference`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumption is that you have one list of programs that are running, and another list of programs that should be running. You want to get a list of any programs that should be running but aren't currently.

The obvious way to do that (especially given that you're sorting the lists anyway) would be to use `std::set_difference`.

```
running_processes = get_process_list();

std::sort(begin, end);
std::sort(running_processes.begin(), running_processes.end());

std::vector<std::string> to_restart;

std::set_difference(begin, end, 
                    running_processes.begin(), running_processes.end(),
                    std::back_inserter(to_restart));

for (auto const &name : to_restart)
    func(name);
```

Comment: Cheers for that, just what i was looking for. Of course it's a set theory problem.